# Request data going into _input:protected instead of data

Tags: jquery, json, rest, cakephp

I have a CakePHP REST backend set up. In it, I have an add function that checks `$this->request->data` and then saves.

When I use Postman (Chrome Extension) and I set up all the data..

`{{domain}}/objects/add` POST

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Data (raw JSON):

```
{
    "Object": {
        "field": "value"
     }
 }
```

It works fine. However, when I attempt to do this with jQuery... I'm seeing the request data is empty, and rather, the data that I expected to be there is in `[_input:protected]` as `Object%5Bfield%5D=value`

Why is it being put in a different part of the object?

My relevant jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php $base_url ?>/objects/add",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: { "Object": { "field": "value" } }
})...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it's already a string, jQuery will by default transform the data into query string format to fit the default content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

On the CakePHP side you are most probably using the request handler component, which will read the raw input (`php://input`, where PHP puts all data that is not sent with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` conten type) depending on the received `Content-Type` header, convert it according to the type, and inject it into the request data.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php#L241-L246](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.10/src/Controller/Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php#L241-L246)**

Now since jQuery sends the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, ie `Object[field]=value`, but sends your `Content-Type` header of `application/json`, the data ends up as raw input, and the request handler will try to parse it as JSON, which will of course fail, and so it won't make it into the request data.

Simple fix on the jQuery side, stringify your JSON data, that way the data is sent as a plain JSON string, and CakePHP can properly parse it:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: JSON.stringify({ "Object": { "field": "value" } })
});
```

See also **http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**

Comment: that seems to have done the trick. wish it could be done with jquery ajax property but this will work fine. thanks.